# Rendering issue in Chrome - Hides part of webpage

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, rendering

My webpage is rendering oddly in Chrome on a Mac. This is just below the fold of the page, but when I highlight the area it comes back into view, also if i use the "inspect element" it just shows the page as it should.

Its also not consistently, it only happens now and again.

Rendering Issue:

http://albertcrm.com/1.png

When I highlight:

http://albertcrm.com/2.png

---

I really have no idea how to even start debugging this, I guess its a CSS issue maybe, or a Chrome Rendering issue, maybe a JS include is taking to long to load?

Comment: Do you have a live site? I mean, one that we can visit? I mean, one that we don't have to log in to?

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle of your code? It will help us help you. :)

Comment: no html nor css, it is useless to ask without any relevant info

Comment: I'd suggest you debug this the hard way: Start removing parts of the page until the rendering issue is fixed, then backtrack and try to isolate the error. I'm currently dealing with the same issue...